# fragment transaction duplication

Tags: android, android-fragments

So to start things of i have a activity and inside that activity i have a tabbedlayout with 3 tabs which are my fragments, now my problem is when i try to pass a value from the activity to lets call it fragmentA the value gets passed correctly BUT the 3 fragments in my tabbedlayout get duplicated. This has been an issue for me for quite some time.

thanks in advance

**Here is my activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".aktivnosti.ActivityTask">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>     

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the code i used to pass my value from **activity -> fragmentA, inside activity.java**

```
        TodoFragment fragment = new TodoFragment();
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragment.setArguments(value);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,"a");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("a");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**viewpager.java**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new TodoFragment();
        case 1:
            return new DoingFragment();
        case 2:
            return new KoncanoFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

FragmentA.xml

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.example.matic.projectplan.aktivnostiFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragmenti.TodoFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_todo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ANOTHER QUESTION EDIT**

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo_list, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        fk_id = bundle.getLong("fk");
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "iz fragmenta" + fk_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fk_id = bundle.getLong("fk");
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "iz fragmenta" + fk_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View popupView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
                final EditText editText = popupView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                adb.setView(popupView);
                adb.setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Dodaj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String naziv = editText.getText().toString();
                                Aktivnost_ ak = new Aktivnost_(naziv, "15-jun", fk_id, "kajetan", "todo");
                                dodajAktivnost(ak);
                                array.add(ak);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dodano", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Prekliči", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Preklical sem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });



        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mmAdapter = new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter(listAktivnosti(fk_id), getContext(), mListener);
        mmAdapter.setOnItemClickListner(new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(long i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PodrobnostiActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key_id", i);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mmAdapter.setOnLongClick(new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter.OnLongClickListener_() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(long i, String item) {
                if (item.equals("doing")) {
                    boolean update_1 = db.updateList(i, item);
                    if (update_1) {
                        //NAREDI SE LEPE ANIMACIJE
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.detach(TodoFragment.this).attach(TodoFragment.this).commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dodano v bazo.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Prislo je do napake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mmAdapter);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: But i cant use a break if i use "return new Fragment()"? or am i missing something here?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want to obtain, but I see that you are creating a TodoFragment both in the view pager and in the Fragment transaction. That doesn't sound correct anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my poor English, first of all create fragment adapter like this
named `MainFragmentAdapter.java`

```
public class MainFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<BaseFragment> fragments;
private List<String> titles;

public MainFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    titles = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public BaseFragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(String title, BaseFragment fragment) {
    titles.add(title);
    fragments.add(fragment);
}
}
```

now create a method in your activity class like this and call it in activity's `onCreate` method

```
private void setupViewPager() {
    MainFragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new MainFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_a), new FragmentA());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_b), new FragmentB());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_c), new FragmentC());
    ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager); 
    mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    TabLayout mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout); 
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

and your activity's xml is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activity_background"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawingListActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dip"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextColor="#5000BFA5" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

hope this can help you now. :-)

Comment: Im not sure how exactly this helps me? Could you please elaborate? beacuse my issue is not with setting up the tabbedlayout that part works fine...the problem start occuring when i try to pass some values and have to use a fragment transaction.

Comment: It fixed my issue with duplication now the problem is because i wanna pass a value from my activity to fragment it makes 2 fragments when i use fragmenttranscation replace.

Comment: I somewhat fixed my problem but am having another issue, with if(bundle !=null) because the code in the if statement is not getting executed? but if i print the value from my bundle it does not return null? i will post my code above, yes